# Archiving DONE tasks in a reverse datetree

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have a `todo.org` file where I place my tasks as TODO headlines. When a task is DONE, a CLOSED timestamp is created, and I usually archive the task to a file `archive.org`. So as to organize my `archive.org` file nicely, I add this line in the header of `todo.org`:

```
#+ARCHIVE: archive.org::datetree/
```

Consequently, DONE tasks are archived into a datetree in `archive.org`, according to their CLOSED timestamps. I'm globally happy with this, but I would like that most recent DONE tasks appear at the top of `archive.org`, and not at the bottom. In other words, I would like archived tasks to be stored in a reversed datetree.

I know that there is a package [`org-reverse-datetree`](https://github.com/akirak/org-reverse-datetree/) but it seems to provide a solution only when working with `org-capture` or refile. I did not manage to use this package for what I want. Is there any simple solution for this?

Thanks !

Comment: Does setting `org-archive-reversed-order` to `t` work?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this setting! However, it does not seem to work.